# How many Hunger dice apply to a split dice pool?

Tags: world-of-darkness, vampire-the-masquerade-5e

Making this a separate question from [this VTM question which was too broad](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/138119/is-my-interpretation-of-vampire-the-masquerade-5th-ed-combat-correct?noredirect=1#comment348500_138119)

How many Hunger dice do you use when you've split your dice pool to get multiple actions?

For instance, Juana has a dice pool of 7 and 1 on the Hunger track. Normally she'd roll 6 normal dice and 1 Hunger die. If Juana splits her dice pool into 4 dice and 3 dice to get 2 actions, how does her 1 Hunger die apply?

Does she still just have the 1 hunger die, and choose whether it is in the 4 dice pool or the 3 dice pool? Or does she have to roll a Hunger die in both of those 'mini-pools'?

Comment: It's odd; the only reference to splitting die pools is in the "multiple opponents" description. There's no other mechanic that uses it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Split die pools are still die pools, just smaller. The Hunger dice are in each of them.