# How does surprise work in Vampire combat?

Tags: combat, world-of-darkness, surprise, vampire-the-masquerade-5e

Making this a separate question from [this VTM question which was too broad](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/138119/is-my-interpretation-of-vampire-the-masquerade-5th-ed-combat-correct)

One side in a fight has achieved **Surprise** (p300). Call them Janet & John. The rules say that they make the surprise attack against Difficulty 1.

So is Turn 1 of combat supposed to be a surprise round where Janet & John deal out damage and there is no opposed defence/attack roll by the folk they are attacking? (Dick & Jane)

Basically are Janet & John calculating damage on number of successes rolled minus the 1 success required for Difficulty 1? So Dick & Jane don’t get to react until Turn 2?

Or do Dick & Jane get an action in Turn 1?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Surprise rounds come from things like ambushes. If you're giving Janet and John surprise, then Dick and Jane should have had the chance to perceive that an attack was coming *before* the combat starts. Insight, Awareness, Streetwise…something that would allow them not to be caught by surprise.

If Dick and Jane each fail to detect the oncoming threat, then, yes; John and Janet make their attack rolls at Difficulty 1 against them. It's a bad day for Dick and Jane.